# Quadratic upper bound for $\log(1+\exp(x))$

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a (tight) quadratic upper bound for the function $\log(1+\exp(x))$ $\forall x$. Is there any way to construct quadratic upper bounds?

Comment: There exists $c$ such that $(1 + e^x) \le ce^{x^2}$ for every $x$. Hence, $\log(1+e^x) \le Cx^2$ for some $C$ and $x > x_0$ for some $x_0$.

Comment: @fwd $\log(1+e^x)\le Cx^2$ is false for $x=0$

Comment: @jjagmath right! thanks.

Comment: What do you me mean with "tight" upper bound?

Comment: @jjagmath intuitively $\forall x$, the value of $\log(1+\exp(x))$ to be as close as possible to the upper bound at this particular $x$

Comment: @fta For negative $x$, the function quicly approaches $0$. How do you expect a sharp quadratic upper bound for those values?

Comment: @fta That's clearly impossible. Any quadratic upper bound will tend to infinity as $x$ tends to minus infinity, but $\log(1+\exp(x))$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Also the function is very nearly the *linear* function $x$ for large positive $x$. How do you expect a sharp *quadratic* upper bound for those values?

Answer (score 0):

Well why not $\forall x$ and $x\neq 0$ :

$$\ln(e^x+1)< \sqrt{x^2+1}$$

?

Also see this link https://www.expii.com/t/what-is-quadratic-nd-order-taylor-approximation-323

Comment: Well, I need $\forall x$, not $x>0$ only. Thank you for the link, but I need an upper bound, not an approximation.

Comment: @fta The approximation is a first step , prove it is the second I think .

Comment: Good, simple and $\to +1$

Answer (score -1):

Your request is quite odd. Here's how the function looks like if you zoom out enough:

[image]

and here's how ANY quadratic looks if you zoom out enough:

[image]

Do you see why is not possible to give a quadratic tight bound for the function?

You'll get better results if you allow a broader class of functions.

For example

[image]

or

[image]